# How best to store HTML alongside strings in Cloud Storage

Tags: google-cloud-storage

I have a collection data of, and in each case there is chunk of HTML and a few strings, for example
html: `<div>html...</div>`, name string: `html chunk 1`, date string: `01-01-1999`, location string: `London, UK`. I would like to store this information together as a single cloud storage object. Specifically, I am using Google Cloud Storage. There are two ways I can think of doing this. One is to store the strings as custom metadata, and the HTML as the actual file contents. The other is to store all the information as JSON file, with the HTML as a base64 encoded string.

I want to avoid a situation where after having stored a lot of data, I find there is some limitation to the approach I am using. What is the proper way to do this - is either of these approaches bad practice? Assuming there is no problem with either, I would go with the JSON approach because it is easier to pass around all the data together as a file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't a specific right way to do what you're talking about, there are potential pitfalls and performance criteria but they depend on what you're doing with the data and why. Do you ever need access to the metadata for queries? You won't be able to efficiently do that if you pack everything into one variable as a JSON object. What are you parsing the data with later? does it have built in support for JSON? Does it support something else? Is speed a consideration? Is cloud storage space a consideration? Does a user have the ability to input the html and could they potentially perform some sort of attack? How do you use the data when you retrieve it? How stable is the format of the data? You could use JSON, ProtocolBuffers, packed binary blobs in a length | value based format, base64 with a delimiter, zip files turned into binary blobs, do what suits your application and allows a clean structured design that you can test and maintain.

Comment: Thanks, accessing the metadata for queries is a good point I hadn't thought about.